# Replace strings between two moduls in dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

I need your help please to know if my idea possible is wiht dxl , I have two Modules with number between [.... ] , the problem is in Modul 1 some [numbers] are missing  !

how can I get the [number] from Module 2  ?

**Example:**

Module1: "An engine or motor is a machine designed to convert one form of energy into mechanical energy. See [no number]"

Module2:"An engine or motor is a machine designed to convert one form of energy into mechanical energy. See [123]"

In my Example the missing number between brackets is 123, I want to write this number in Module 1

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

yes, that should be possible.

first, you need some method to identify the corresponding objects. if you have for example some attribute "manually_filled_requirement_id", you walk through Module 1, for each object, get the ID, locate an object in Module 2 with the same ID. Then, the question is, whether you also want to update the requirement text or only the number in brackets, and in the case that the objects contain different numbers, decide which one is the correct number. In the case that you only want to update the number, you could use regular expressions.

If you want to copy the complete text, it's easy:

```
object1."Object Text" = object2."Object Text"
```

Otherwise you have to split the text of object 1 and 2 into three parts:

1. the part up to and including the (first? last?) [ in the text
2. the part between the (first? last?) []
3. the part after the (first? last?) ]

Then you can set

```
object1."Object Text" = part_1_of_object_1 part_2_of_object_2 part 3_of_object_1
```

Regexes you can use for this is:

```
Regexp hasAPlaceForNumber = regexp2 "(^[^\[]+\[)([^\]]*)(\].*$)"
Regexp hasNumber = regexp2 "(^[^\[]+\[)([\d]+)(\].*$)"
```

That is: collect everything from the beginning (^) up to the first [ in match 1, everything following that is not a ] in match 2, everything following up to the end ($) in match 3. The second Regexp matches if part 2 only consists of digits.

Then you can do something like

```
string o1Text = object1."Object Text"""
string o2Text = object2."Object Text""
if ((hasNumber o2Text) and (not hasNumber o1Text) and hasAPlaceForNumber o1Text)
   hasNumber o2Text
   string part_1_of_object_2 = o2Text [match 1]
   string part_2_of_object_2 = o2Text [match 2]
   string part_3_of_object_2 = o2Text [match 3]
   hasAPlaceForNumber o1Text
   string part_1_of_object_1 = o1Text [match 1]
   string part_2_of_object_1 = o1Text [match 2]
   string part_3_of_object_1 = o1Text [match 3]
   object1."Object Text" = part_1_of_object_1 part_2_of_object_1 part_3_of_object_1
else if (...)
```

I have to admit that I am more fluent in perl than in DXL, so it might be that I mixed up some syntax, but you should get the idea.